# How to add Virtual field after querying another Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want the `commentCount` field to show whenever i am accessing the Image model. Here is the code:

```
imageSchema
  .virtual('commentCount')
  .get(async function () {
    const image_id = this._id;
    const commentCount = await Comment.count({ image_id }); 
    return commentCount;
  });
```

In the final output for the image, I get:

```
{ uploaded: 2018-05-04T09:24:46.063Z,
    _id: 5aec26ed56d4491ef4b3d15a,
    title: 'Another snake',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem ipsa autem culpa ea enim itaque, illo inventore obcaecati commodi minus?',
    photo: '4a0831c2-f8d0-459d-ab06-794ee26c6c87.jpeg',
    __v: 0,
    commentCount: Promise { <pending> },
    id: '5aec26ed56d4491ef4b3d15a' } ]
```

commentCount is a promise, even after i await the Promise. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Well if you do `let image = await Image.findById("5aec26ed56d4491ef4b3d15a"); console.log(await image.commentCount);` then That should basically give you an idea. You appear to be wanting to send a response showing the "related" count from another collection. This was a novel idea, but it's really the wrong way to go about it. Look at the `$lookup` operator of MongoDB instead. Bottom line is a virtual "getter" is just a function. It can "return a promise", but you cannot really make it "resolve a promise" before the object gets serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this while creating the schema itself:

```
var imageSchema= new Schema({
        commentCount : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.count, ref: 'Comment'},
        pid: String,
        oFile: String
});
```

Comment: It throws this error,
`TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `commentCount.type``